# Is there a list available for EventTrigger EventNames?

Tags: wpf, events

I do not seem to find a list of available EventNames used in EventTriggers for different UI elements in WPF. I know some of the commonly used Event Names like

1. Loaded
2. Click

But it would be nice to get a list of all the event names available for example for a `Grid` Element.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The best resource for this would probably be Microsoft's documentation. For instance this is a list of all the events for a WPF grid.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid_events(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ok. I was looking under Event Trigger documentation for a list. My bad.

Answer (score 11):

In Visual Studio you can also see the list of available events for a certain control.
They all should be usable as event triggers.

Just click on the respective control in the designer and take a look at the properties tab.

There should be a "flash" symbol at the top right corner of the properties tab. By clicking on it, you can change from "property view" to the "event view" of the control you selected.
You will then see all available events for the selected control.

You can then search for the documentation in the event your are interested in.

Comment: Ah, brilliant! :)